# Adding value obtained from another table to all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables one called slotLength and one called schedule. Here are their descriptions:

```
+------------+------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| Field      | Type | Null | Key | Default  | Extra |
+------------+------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| slotLength | time | NO   | PRI | 00:00:00 |       |
+------------+------+------+-----+----------+-------+


+-----------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| dayId     | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| dayName   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| startHour | time        | YES  |     | 08:00:00 |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

I know that they do not have the best design, but I am still learning. Also, they are just an experiment so please ignore the mistakes in their desigin.

Before I proceed, let's assume that slotLenght table contains just one row and let's call it's value slotSize.

I want to compute startHour + slotSize * n, where startHour represents values from startHour column in schedule table and n is a number. To be more specific, let's see an example,
if slotSize is "01:00:00" and a value from startHour is "09:00:00", then startHour + 
slorSize * 3 I expect to have the value "12:00:00".

How the query should look like? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can multiply against a time field in SQL. Adding and subtracting is fairly easy, but multiplication would get a bit more complicated.  You can use `ADDTIME()` for part of the equation, but I'm unsure of the multiplication part.  Some heavier mathematics might have to come into play for that.

Here is a list of MySQL time functions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

EDIT:

Perhaps something along the lines of converting to seconds, multiplying, and then converting back would work.  I'm not overly familiar with MySQL so hopefully someone will give you the query your looking for, but this should get you started to try on your own.

```
SELECT ADDTIME(startHour, SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(slotSize) * 3)) AS Calculated
FROM Table, OtherTable
```

Not sure if ^ Table is needed so if it works without it forget if not throw it in there to select startHour.

I believe this is close to what your looking for.  As I said being unfamiliar with MySQL errors most likely lie in wait especially with the `ADDTIME()` function as I believe it requires the date portion to work.

Comment: Nice ideea to convert the time to seconds. Thank you. But there remains one problem: how do i take slotSize and startHour from 2 different tables?

Comment: Sorry forgot the ending to that edit coming shortly.

Comment: @Paul92 Let me know if this works for you or not, as I may be able to help with a few errors should they arise.

Comment: I did not need an insert, just the select. Also, I need to specify a value for n. Also I added a where clause and other small modifications, but I have not asked for them. Please remove the first line in the query (the insert) and change n in order to help others too. Anyway, thank you for your help, i solved the problem.

Comment: @Paul92 Editted. Glad you got what you were looking for.